# Getting actions probabilities instead of an unique prediction in Stable Baselines 3 SAC?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, prediction, probability

I try to understand how getting an actions probability table instead of an unique prediction in stable baselines 3 SAC in order to override 'predict' method to filter invalid actions. I guess the good way to do that is to remove invalid actions from table and resize probabilities.

Models predictions can be deterministic or not but i can't find any function that returns action probabilities table (such function was available in SB2 if i remember well...)

I read these topics but they are not about SAC :

https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/1347

https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/568

https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/385

Best regards.